# queries through mysqli don't update performance_schema

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am trying to make use of the performance_schema database in my WAMP stack.

- My php version is 5.6
- I have added "performance_schema" under the
  [mysqld] heading in the my.ini config file.

If I run any query directly from mysql.exe or through phpMyAdmin, the queries will be automatically added to the performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest table.

If I run a query through the deprecated php `mysql` extension, the queries will be added to the table.

Unfortunately if I run a query from php's `mysqli` extension, the queries don't get added/updated in the performance schema table.

I can't find anything in the mysqli documentation about the performance_schema database.

Does anybody have any information on what might be going on? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For people who may also run into this issue..

I could not find much info on this but I have found out the issue.

I am using mySQL version 5.6 which does not support the use of predefined statements in the performance schema data.

I had been using predefined statements in mysqli, which is why nothing was showing up.

In mySQL 5.7 a new table has been added to the performance_schema database called "prepared-statements-instances" which I believe is where the prepared statement digests are stored.